# How to find the dual point of a line geometrically?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, poincare-duality

I'm learning hyperbolic geometry by following [Prof NJ Wildberger videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvP8VtyhzXs&list=PLIljB45xT85CN9oJ4gYkuSQQhAtpIucuI). So far I know how to find the dual of a point (which is a line) geometrically (using pen, paper, and ruler). Here's an example:

[image]

In the given example, I started with point A and constructed its dual-line, FG. This is the process:

1. Find two arbitrary lines that cross the circle in two points (each) while passing through point A (here: AB and AC).
2. Find the other two intersects of the lines and the circle, D and E.
3. Construct the quadrilateral and the diagonal lines by connecting all the combinations of B, C, D, and E (i.e. BC, BE, CD, and EF - we already had BD and CE).
4. This will give you points F and G and connecting them will give you the dual line of A.

Now my question is, how can I find A if I was given FG? I know how to find A algebraically but I'm interested in the geometrical approach.

Comment: It's the intersection of the duals of any two points $F,G$ on the line.

Comment: @Berci That's it. Thanks.